# Work with different schemas in Doctrine

Tags: oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm, oracle11g, doctrine

I am using doctrine2 with oracle. There are several schemas schema1 and schema2. When I create a form with the following content

```
// ....
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // ....
    $builder
        ->add('userPartner', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'SoftclubTopbyBundle:Party',
                'property' => 'legalName',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'multiple' => true,
        ))
    ;
    // ....
}
//...
```

the symfony throws me an exception:

```
MappingException in MappingException.php line 37:
The class 'Softclub\TopbyBundle\Entity\Nsi\NsiChainStore' was not found in
the chain configured namespaces Softclub\TopbyBundle\Entity\Topby
```

I have the following setting in the config.yml

```
entity_managers:
    default:
        connection: default
        mappings:
            SoftclubTopbyBundle: { type: yml, dir: Resources/config/doctrine/topby, prefix: Softclub\TopbyBundle\Entity\Topby }
    nsi:
        connection: nsi
        mappings:
            SoftclubTopbyBundle: { type: yml, dir: Resources/config/doctrine/nsi, prefix: Softclub\TopbyBundle\Entity\Nsi }
```

and also the following relationship between the two entities

```
Softclub\TopbyBundle\Entity\Topby\Party:
    manyToOne:
        chainStore:
            targetEntity: Softclub\TopbyBundle\Entity\Nsi\NsiChainStore
            cascade: {  }
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                CHAIN_STORE_ID:
                    referencedColumnName: ID
            orphanRemoval: false
```

what can I do wrong?

Comment: I usually separate two schema in two different bundle, so is more easy to doctrine to understand which bundle must manage the proper database and entity related. But i can't related each other especially with two different connections.

Comment: Hi! I broke the project into 2 bundles, the second bundle has moved the entities and the metadata from the schema2, changed the config settings.yml and get the same exception "MappingException". As I understand it the problem is that different connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for the answers. As Matteo said, the entities were placed in a separate bundle. The problem was solved as follows

```
default:
    connection: default
    mappings:
        SoftclubTopbyBundle: ~
        SoftclubNsiBundle: ~

# for generate entities
topby:
    connection: default
    mappings:
        SoftclubTopbyBundle: ~
nsi:
    connection: nsi
    mappings:
        SoftclubNsiBundle: ~
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not make doctrine relations over different connections. You can use event listener for that purpose. 
For instance, one entity (say Note) has some property which is reference to another entity (say User) belonging to another entity manager (connection). The Note entity persists User's ID as foreign key.
Event listener is used to instantiate User object by using it's ID whenever the Note object is loaded (postLoad event).

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Doctrine events: 
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events

Regarding the form, put option entity manager with 'nsi' if 'userPartner' is mapped to that connection.

```
'em'=>'nsi'
```

Have not worked with Oracle, hope this helps.